# Disable split screen android

Tags: android, split-screen

Good Day,

I would like to disable split screen, and get the result what is shown in "Expected Result" screenshot. (Toast with text "App doesn't support split screen")

In the "Actual Result" screen you can see how `android:resizeableActivity="false"` affect on the app, but still split-screen enabled. 
How can I disable it at all ?

Actual Result:

[image]
Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: So you want to disable the split screen feature of your android device? I hope it is not possible.

Comment: @greenapps I have edited the question

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I want to disable split screen feature as it is on Expected Result picture

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What I found ?

We can't set `android:resizeableActivity="false"` in the `<application>` tag it is ignored. (mistake google documentation)

It works when I set it to the main activity

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: For future reference: Using `android:resizeableActivity="false"` shows a warning when not having min api set to 24 - it can be ignored because pre-api 24 ignores the tag as it has no value or action.

Comment: Note that if you have a bunch of activities you don't need to put this flag on each one. You can put the flag in your root/launch activity and any activities that start in a new task. All other activities that are part of the same task will inherit this flag.

Comment: The flag `android:resizeableActivity="false"` now works in `application` tag.

Answer (score 11):

Add android:resizeableActivity="false" in application tag at manifest.xml file.

```
         <application
                android:name=".activity.MyApplication"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/btn_share_myapplication"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:resizeableActivity="false"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <activity
                    android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        <activity... />
        </application>
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to set minHeight and miWidth as in example here:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
<layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
      android:defaultWidth="600dp"
      android:gravity="top|end"
      android:minHeight="450dp"
      android:minWidth="300dp" />
</activity>
```

Taken from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Comment: For future reference: This sets the width and height of the layout that is used when the mode is set to split screen. **This does not disable split screen** - it sets the condition under which the app responds to the split screen