# How to open my app in full screen if split screen is activate

Tags: android

I am working with kiosk app. In my app there is issue related split screen option.

I set `resizeableActivity=false` in `manifests.xml`

If user long press on recent button, screen is split and user can access all the recent app.

**How can I disable split screen?**

or

**How to resize my app in full height if user split screen programmatically?**

I already blocked recent app on click on recent button. But if user long press on recent button, user can split screen and can access recent apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable split screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259027/disable-split-screen-android)

Comment: I already tried that way. But didn't get succeed.